# Could not load a dependency of my custom dll exception

Tags: dll, dependencies, .net-assembly

I have written a custom data-access library (aka DAL) which references `[Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.dll]` as a dependency.
When my client app which has a reference to the DAL dll, try to use one of the DAL's methods, an exception is thrown:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=6.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

If I, of course, put the EnterpriseLibrary dll in my client app bin folder (or make the client reference it...), there is no error, but it's a 'crooked' solution.

What is not clear to me is why referenceing ONLY my custom DAL dll is not enough?
And, is there a way to only reference the DAL dll without referencing EnterpriseLibrary dll's directly?

Comment: why it's a crooked solution? If your assembly referneced  `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.dll` then you need to add it or it has to be present on the machine where you want to run the app

Comment: @PawełŁukasik - Because my client app shouldn't care about the DAL's layer implementation.. As a client, I want only reference the DAL.

Comment: it does not. It care on your abstraction, but your abstraction currently uses EnterpriseLibrary. You could say the same about .net framework libs - they had to be present on the machine if your client app should be used. And they are though they are installed in Windows folder. If you want to get rid of external dlls try Fody.Costura.